# Why Solve is not working?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I'm new here and I'm a newbie also with Mathematica, so probably this an easy and stupid question. If you have suggestion on how can I learn at least the basics of the language, I appreciate it.

I'm trying to solve a simple symbolic equation, but it says that there aren't solutions:

```
Solve[(1 - T)*(1/p + 1/k - 2/d) == 1/p + 1/k - 2/d*Exp[\[Omega]e] && 
  e > 0 && 0 < T && T < 1 && p >= 1 && k >= 1 && d >= 1, e]
```

As you can see the equation it's easy and I'm expecting something like:
$$e = \frac{\log[\cdots]}{\omega}$$
but the output is:

```
{{}}
```

Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: One problem `\[Omega]e` should be `\[Omega] e` or `\[Omega] * e`.

Comment: Also, specify the domain as `Reals`

Comment: How can I specify the domain? I was expecting that by telling the inequalities it automatically understands that I'm working with Reals

Comment: Also, do you know why is not raining any error for the forgotten `*`? What is understanding?

Comment: In any case I get `Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: `\[Omega]e` is interpreted as a variable name. The given equations have the correct syntax. `Solve` tells you there is no solution for that system. After the correction, you have not indicated that `\[Omega]` is real. You can either add the constraint `Element[\[Omega], Reals]` or specify the domain as `Reals`. From the docs, "Solve[expr, vars, dom]" where you want `dom` to be `Reals`

Comment: for a start just write \[Omega] e and omit all conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Solve[(1 - T)*(1/p + 1/k - 2/d) == 1/p + 1/k - 2/d*Exp[ω*e], e] /. C[1] -> 0
    
(*  {{e -> Log[(2 k p + d k T + d p T - 2 k p T)/(2 k p)]/ω}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Please have a look into Menu/Help/WolframDocumenmtation/Solve. There you find an explanation along with lots of examples.